# How to Calculate NDWI Value in Arcgis 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, landsat, normalized-difference-water-index

I want to delineate surface water feature of my Landsat raster image and also want to calculate the area of water body. I have learned through internet that NDWI can be used to delineate open water feature.

How can I calculate NDWI value using arcgis 10.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the NDWI using basic raster calculator in arcmap.
You need to use Landsat bands 3 and 5 (Landsat 8 OLI), and simply calculate a new raster with an algebraic expression:

```
(Band 3 - Band 5)/(Band 3 + Band 5)
```

You should preferably use images corrected to TOA.
In this example I have bands 3 and 5
[image]

The result is a raster with values between -1 and 1 (hence the "Normalized" in the index name. You can see in the histogram that water values are close to 1, and the rest of the pixels are between -1 and 0. 
[image]

So to calculate the area, you first have to extract these values into a separate raster with a raster calculator or reclassify tool, the result of which you can convert into a vector layer, which you can then easily calculate its dimensions.

Comment: For landsat 4-5 TM and landsat 7 ETM, what will be the equation ?

Comment: The equivalent Green and Near infra-Red bands, so bands 2 and 4

Comment: I think you can give my answer .http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199507/how-to-calculate-area-of-water-body-after-calculating-ndwi-in-arcgis-10-1